# Can folders be added to a column in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a document library with a column named "Class" and there are additional column settings in a choice (drop-down) menu. The additional choices are Math, Science, English, History.

Is there a way to add a folder to each of these classes?

The "New Folder" button on the Documents tab makes it easy to create a new folder, but that gives me a folder at the same level as the classes.  I also get the same result if I open the Library in Explorer and create a new folder; it displays at the same level as the classes (see image).
[Folder at same level as class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqPkZ.png)

I want the folder to act like a sub-folder in Windows Explorer. Imagine that each class was a folder in Explorer with subfolders inside. For example: inside Math would be folders for Homework,  Practice Quizzes, and Tests (see image). 
[Sub-folder in Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdImJ.png)
Can this be done in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to merge the two different ways that metadata can be assigned to documents: columns and folders.

In a traditional file system, you can't add extra columns of information to a document, so to organize anything you need to create hierarchical folder structures wherein each folder represents a piece of metadata about the document. SharePoint libraries free you from the file folder model so you can tag documents with metadata directly, then create different views to slice and dice and filter the documents as desired.

They are very different organizational schemes, so you should be sure that you actually need an old-fashioned folder hierarchy in SharePoint before you go any further.

If you absolutely need to have folder locations in SharePoint match up with column values, you have a some options that you might be able to exploit.

**Set Default Column Values on a Per Folder Basis**

This technique will automatically set the correct column metadata of a document based on where it is uploaded in the library, and is useful if users are using explorer view, or if they're used to working with folders and don't like having to fill in metadata.

1. Manually add all the folders for your column values at the root level of the library
2. In the settings for the list, click "Column Default Value Settings"
3. For each folder, set the column value to default to the value that corresponds to the folder name.

**Show or Hide Folders from the List View**

Folders are considered items in the list, which is why they show up in the list view. In the settings for the view, there's a section called "Folders." There you can tell it to show all items inside folders (the default setting) or to show all items without folders.

Assuming the metadata and folders are sync'd up, consider creating a view that groups by column value and shows all items without folders, or else create a view that does not group by the column value but instead shows folders.

**Use the Content Organizer Feature to automatically move documents to the correct folders**

The Content Organizer feature creates a "drop-off library" on your site. You can then create rules for the drop off library (in site settings) that determine where documents should be routed.

The big advantage with this is that people can upload a document to the drop-off library and fill in the metadata, then a rule can move it to the correct library and the correct folder based on what metadata was filled in.

There is an option to automatically capture document uploads from a specific library and send them to the Drop Off Library for routing, so users don't necessarily need to navigate to the Drop Off Library themselves.

**Consider using document sets**

Document Sets are folders that can have metadata assigned to them, and come with a slew of additional functionality, such as the ability to cascade column values down to all documents within the set.

They're not a cure-all, though, and they have their quirks. You'll see odd behavior, for example, if you start trying to nest folders beneath document sets.